# Posting .net MVC 3 FromsCollection from other domain with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, actionresult

OK, I'm totally new to .NET MVC3 and I've run into a problem.

I am developing a mobile application using Jquery mobile and I wish to send data from the mobile application to the web-page. On the server I have this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    public ActionResult Save(FormCollection actionValues) {
        int age = Int32.Parse(actionValues["age"]);
        string fn = actionValues["first_name"];
        string ln = actionValues["last_name"];
        CreateAndStorePersonModel(age,fn,ln); // Dummy method, not important
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200); // Thanks to 3nigma for this
    }
```

What I want is to be able to get the actionValues and store them in a model, then store this model into a database. For the sake of this example we'll assume I want to store a "Person" with attributes: "first_name, last_name, age". Also I might expand this model in the future.

From the mobile app i run the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://external.url/Save",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true, // default serialization (do I even need this?)
        data: {
            "age": data_age,
            "first_name": data_fn,
            "last_name": data_ln,
        },
        success: function(d) { alert("Success: "+d},
    }).error(function(data, errorTxt, jqXHR) {
    alert('Error: '+errorTxt);
});;
```

I got the 500 internal error, but thanks to 3nigma this is no longer the case.

EDIT:

When testing from my webserver I get a http 302 "Found" when checking inspector, but the data does not get saved. When compiling to mobile phone the .error handler kicks inn with "parseerror", but the data gets saved. Any idea why?

Answer:

The 302 "Found" came because I returned a view (thanks to 3nigma) Should return this:

```
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 is internal server error

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection actionValues) {
        int age = long.Parse(actionValues["age"]);// there error seems to be here you are boxing long into int
        string fn = actionValues["first_name"]; 
        string ln = actionValues["last_name"];
        CreateAndStorePersonModel(age,fn,ln); 
    }
```

try instead

```
int age = Int32.Parse(actionValues["age"].ToString());
```

---

answering the comments

you dont need to include anything just return Json from the ActionResult like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection actionValues) {
     //your code here
     return Json(new {IsSuccess="success" });
    }
```

and in the ajax success handler you can access it like

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://external.url/Save",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true, // default serialization (do I even need this?)
        data: {
            "age": data_age,
            "first_name": data_fn,
            "last_name": data_ln,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: "+data.IsSuccess}, //will alert Success: success
    }).error(function(data, errorTxt, jqXHR) {
    alert('Error: '+errorTxt);
});;
```

Comment: Ah lol, I've edited my post. Thanks. Kinda just typed that on the top of my head. But there should not be any problems with CORS doing as I did, right?

Comment: probably not if you set the appropraite accept headers in the response, also you should have edited the question, not change it bcoz earlier you mentioned internal server error and now you have removed it ...

Comment: Ah, so true. I'm new to this site, so sorry about that.

Comment: no problem since you mentioned it in another edit `:)`, have you resolved your problem

Comment: Its even more weird than before. I get an alert with "error: parseerror" when running on the mobile application, and I get a "302 Found" when testing from the webpage. I think it might be CORS-related?

Comment: 302 means redirection, your some code some where is trying to redirect the request, and the parser error may be because you are not returning the json?? its difficult to tell from the code you have provided what are you returning from the ActionResult, if it has been related to CORS you would get response 200 OK along with error message telling that the domain does not support the cross domain requests et

Comment: what version of jquery you are using

Comment: Spot on! I see now that I return a view. So there you have it. What should I return to say "OK"? return true?

Comment: Nvm. google is my friend:    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);

Comment: glad that it worked... you can also return json like `return Json(new{success="success"})`

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I need to change the response header to indicate json then? And if I return "success", does this get catched by the ajax success handler?

Comment: edited the answer to show how you can access the returned value in the ajax success handler

Answer (score 0):

it may be your json data syntax which is creating issue

```
data: 
{
    "age"         : intValue,
    "first_name"  : stringValueinSingleQuotes,
    "last_name"   : stringValueinSingleQuotes
}
```

more over you can have success : Handler() attribute in the $.ajax call. Handler() method will be called if call is a success.

Comment: Great input, though it is not the data field which causes the problem. But adding the success handler to the ajax call is a great though. This way I do not need to do it as jsonp. So thanks for that :)